# Fill NaN values by other column

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1 COL2 
SEQ1 SEQ1_67
SEQ2 NaN
SEQ3 SEQ3_7788
SEQ5 SEQQ0
SEQ6 NaN
SEQ7 NaN
```

and I woule like to fill `COL2` `NaN` values by the `COL1` corresponding content
and get

```
COL1 COL2 
SEQ1 SEQ1_67
SEQ2 SEQ2
SEQ3 SEQ3_7788
SEQ5 SEQQ0
SEQ6 SEQ6
SEQ7 SEQ7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.COL2 = df.COL2.mask(df.COL1.eq(df.COL2))
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df.COL1.eq(df.COL2), 'COL2'] = np.nan
```

---

```
print (df)
   COL1       COL2
0  SEQ1    SEQ1_67
1  SEQ2        NaN
2  SEQ3  SEQ3_7788
3  SEQ5      SEQQ0
4  SEQ6        NaN
5  SEQ7        NaN
```

For reverse simplier is use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df.COL2 = df.COL2.fillna(df.COL1)
```

Comment: oups sorry I mixted the df, the first one is the result I should get

Comment: @chippycentra - Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.where`:

```
In [1334]: df.COL2 = np.where(df.COL2.isna(), df.COL1, df.COL2)

In [1335]: df
Out[1335]: 
   COL1       COL2
0  SEQ1    SEQ1_67
1  SEQ2       SEQ2
2  SEQ3  SEQ3_7788
3  SEQ5      SEQQ0
4  SEQ6       SEQ6
5  SEQ7       SEQ7
```